# Can scarcely or scarcely

Tags: word-usage

Is there any difference between the two

I can scarcely see at night and

I scarcely can see at night.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an auxiliary verb or modal with scarcely, you usually put the auxiliary verb or modal first.

So it's more common and idiomatic  to say 'I can scarcely see at night' than 'I scarcely can see at night'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the two

> scarcely can

means not really able to do *something*

> scarcely see

means not really able to see *something*

Your sentence would usually be used as

> I can scarcely see at night.

means you have difficulty seeing at night (because it's dark is implied).

> I scarcely can see at night.

means you have difficulty seeing at night because t's night, regardless of the amount of light.